# IQueryable (PLINQ) peek and group Linq methods to run in different tasks

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable, plinq

I want to divide a `IQueryable` into several ones, like the image below, extracted from the explanation of the [.AsParallel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq). But instead of running all in parallel, I want to run some of them together, and then join later.

[image]

So, the question is, there is any way to group this methods at will? Thank you

**Update With Example**

I have several `linq` methods, I want to peek specific `linq` to run grouped in the same task. Possible?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that the image helps much at describing what you are trying to do. Could you explain it in more detail using words?

Comment: I just added an example